# Need SQL that list of names of suppliers offering only computers and trucks

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table name Test with two columns namely: "Supplier Name" and "Product Name". Now I want Supplier name that deals in Only 'Truck' and 'Computer'. As shown below the result of that query should return 'Ajit' only.
Though Gaurav also deals in 'Truck' and 'Computer', but he also deals in 'BC', so query result should return only supplier name as Ajit!

**Test:**

```
**SuppliarName**        **Product Name**
Gaurav              Truck
Ajit                Computer
Rahul               Jhadu
Gaurav              Computer
Gaurav              BC
Ajit                Truck
```

Comment: School work? Which dbms product are you using? (Answer may depent on it...)

Comment: yes school work though query in any dbms will work here and it would be best if it is sql server

Comment: self join, with NOT EXISTS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because do your own home work

Comment: Me to, at least if OP doesn't make any effort writing queries.

Comment: OOH common School work doesn't mean that i am in school but I am trying to solve a query that is asked by someone i came across this while solving other query

Comment: @jarlh you mean self join *or* not exists, no point of having a self join with not exists...

Comment: Please edit your questions to include your efforts so far. this is a fairly simple thing to do, but SO is not a "write my code for me" service.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, it is... self join to get both truck and computer, not exists to make sure nothing else...

Comment: @jarlh no need for both in the same query. please see my answer for details.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, but does you queries make sure BOTH truck and computer exist, but nothing else?

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, I might have misunderstood the question. I thought that it was either one of them... in the case when they are both needed, then you are correct and you need either a triple self join or a self join with not exists.

Comment: Well, it could be either way, the question isn't very clear if both truck and computer is required, or just one of them.

Comment: Bothe Truck and Computer is required

Comment: I already stated with a table that i need the supplier name that deals in Computer and Truck both only

Comment: Glad to help. Check the other answer as well, it should also work. Please accept one of them so that people will know the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't going to answer this question before the OP would show his efforts, but jarlh comment about self join and not exists convinced me to show that it's possible with either one of this options alone:

self left join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.SuppliarName
FROM Tbl t1
LEFT JOIN Tbl t2 ON(t1.SuppliarName = t2.SuppliarName 
                    AND t2.ProductName NOT IN('Truck', 'Computer'))
WHERE t1.ProductName IN('Truck', 'Computer')
AND t2.SuppliarName IS NULL;
```

not exists:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.SuppliarName
FROM Tbl t1
WHERE t1.ProductName IN('Truck', 'Computer')
AND NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM Tbl t2
  WHERE t1.SuppliarName = t2.SuppliarName 
  AND t2.ProductName NOT IN('Truck', 'Computer')
)
```

[see fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/96ff2/4)

**Update** I might have misunderstood the question. if the requirement is for both computer and truck to be sold by the supplier, then a triple self join or a self join with not exists will do the trick:

triple self join:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.SuppliarName
FROM Tbl t1
INNER JOIN Tbl t2 ON(t1.SuppliarName = t2.SuppliarName 
                     AND t1.ProductName <> t2.ProductName) 
LEFT JOIN Tbl t3 ON(t1.SuppliarName = t3.SuppliarName 
                    AND t3.ProductName NOT IN('Truck', 'Computer'))
WHERE t1.ProductName ='Truck'
AND t2.ProductName = 'Computer'
AND t3.SuppliarName IS NULL;
```

self join with not exists:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.SuppliarName
FROM Tbl t1
INNER JOIN Tbl t2 ON(t1.SuppliarName = t2.SuppliarName 
                     AND t1.ProductName <> t2.ProductName) 
WHERE t1.ProductName ='Truck'
AND t2.ProductName = 'Computer'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tbl t3 
    WHERE t3.SuppliarName = t1.SuppliarName
    AND t3.ProductName NOT IN('Truck', 'Computer')
)
```

[see fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/96ff2/10)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1 t2 
                WHERE t1.SuppliarName = t2.SuppliarName 
                AND t2.[Product Name] = 'Computer')
 AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1 t3 
                WHERE t1.SuppliarName = t3.SuppliarName 
                AND t3.[Product Name] = 'Truck')
 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1 t4 
                WHERE t1.SuppliarName = t4.SuppliarName 
                AND t4.[Product Name] NOT IN ('Computer', 'Truck'))
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fc6f9/1

Comment: You are over complicating a simple query. no need for all this code where a simple left join will suffice.

Comment: @ZoharPeled There might be a slight uncertainty with a question, but I understood that Supplier needs to have both Computers and Truck and nothing else, which can be done in other ways, but not much simpler. (You have just updated your answer with this, while I was typing :))

Comment: Actually, my comment was written when I thought it should be at least one of computer and truck. After editing my answer, I think that there's not much difference between your suggestion and mine in terms of code complexity. sql server's optimizer might even have the same execution plan for all three options we came up with :-)